# How to have drupal views show dynamic content based on node

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, view, cck

Is it possible to have views show a query based on the current node (not 1 set node but any node)

my situation:

A user submits a node with information

another user can donate to that node from another content type using 2 fields: node reference (to pick the node) and integer (to enter donation amount)

I need a block view to show all the donated amounts for the current displayed node

(would be even better if someone told me how to just all the donated amounts up to show the total amount!)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need dynamic filtering, views arguments is your friend.

After you add fields and filters, add an argument Content: node reference (the name would be whatever you chose to name it, but make sure it's node reference).

In the argument setting, for "Action to take if argument is not present" click on provide default argument and choose Node ID from URL, do validation.

Add a block view and enable it on the block settings page. It's only going to show on the appropriate nodes.

Check [this tutorial](http://drupalsn.com/learn-drupal/drupal-tutorials/creating-dynamic-blocks-using-cck-node-reference-and-views-drupal) for more detail.

To do calculations, take a look at [Views Calc](http://drupal.org/project/views_calc) module.

Comment: Ok im trying to wrap my head around this, when i made this view block it should show all of the nodes made with the referrer set to this one?

also do you think its possible to make a dynamic button? so when someone click on it (from the page with the info) and goto the donation content type the referrer field is already selected?

Comment: The block should show all nodes that reference the current one.

Comment: As to your second question, check out Node Reference URL Widget http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url